# Matrix groups generated by translation and inversion in the unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha$ be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, and consider the subgroup $G$ of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ generated by inversion in the unit sphere and translation by $\alpha$.  That is, consider $G=\langle S, T \rangle$, in which

$$ S:= \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right) \quad \text{and} \quad T:= \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & \alpha \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right).$$

For which $\alpha$ is the structure of $G$ known?  Of particular interest to me is the following: for which $\alpha$ do we obtain $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \subset G$?

Perhaps this occurs iff $1/\alpha$ is an algebraic integer?

Comment: A negative result. Suppose $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer and not a unit. Then it lies in some $\mathcal{O}_K$ where it is contained in a maximal ideal $m$. $G$ is contained in $\text{SL}_2(\mathcal{O}_K)$ and $T$ is contained in the kernel of the quotient map $\text{SL}_2(\mathcal{O}_K) \to \text{SL}_2(\mathcal{O}_K/m)$, so in particular translation by $1$ is not contained in $G$ (as it does not lie in the image of this map).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  I don't see how your reasoning leads to a negative result to my potential iff.  I consider the case in which 1/$\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, not where $\alpha$ necessarily is.

Comment: I wasn't addressing that case. You asked the question for $\alpha$ algebraic and I addressed a special case. ("Negative result" here means "here is a case in which the desired property does not hold," not "here is a counterexample to your conjecture.")

Comment: Just a minor remark: it's known that $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a maximal discrete subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. So if $\alpha$ is real, then this subgroup either doesn't contain $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, or is "really big" in the sense that it is not discrete in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be the number field generated by $\alpha$. Consider the prime factorization of the fractional ideal $(\alpha)$. If this prime factorization contains a prime ideal $P$ to a positive exponent, then $\alpha$ lies in the localization $S^{-1}\mathcal{O}_K$ away from all of the prime ideals in the prime factorization which occur with negative exponents. $P$ is a prime ideal in this localization, so we can take the quotient by $P$, which gives rise to a map

$$\text{SL}_2(S^{-1} \mathcal{O}_K) \to \text{SL}_2(S^{-1} \mathcal{O}_K/P).$$

$G$ is contained in the domain of this map, as is $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, but the image of $T$ under this map is the identity since $\alpha \equiv 0 \bmod P$, so the image of $G$ is generated by $S$ and in particular does not contain the image of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Thus a necessary condition for the desired property to hold is that the prime factorization of $(\alpha)$ contains only negative exponents. This is equivalent to $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ being an algebraic integer. However, I don't know how to prove that the property holds unless $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is in fact an integer (in which case it's straightforward).

**Edit:** I believe your conjecture is false. If $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \subset G$ and $\alpha$ is real, then it follows that a fundamental domain of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acting on the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ is a union of fundamental domains of $G$ acting on $\mathbb{H}$; in particular, the latter have smaller hyperbolic area than the former. But if $\alpha$ is an algebraic number with a real conjugate of absolute value greater than $1$, then WLOG $\alpha$ is this conjugate (the property of containing $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is invariant under Galois action), and it is straightforward to write down a fundamental domain which has larger hyperbolic area than a fundamental domain of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, which is a contradiction.

As an explicit example where $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is an algebraic integer, take $\alpha = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: The hyperbolic geometry can be replaced with an argument about explicit coset representatives of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})/G$ or something like that using a version of the Euclidean algorithm, and probably this can be extended to $\mathbb{C}$, but I think the above is easier to visualize.